# What happens after the Nest access token expires?

Tags: rest, nest-api

Question says it all. I couldn't find anywhere in the API that states what happens when it expires. Do you have to open that "Works with Nest" webpage again and get a new authorization code? Or, using the same authorization code, just get a new token? And how will Nest indicate the token has expired?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Expiration date comes back in the OAuth response and is set to 10 years in the future, which is practically forever. That gives Nest quite a few years to come up with a refresh or expiration story.

Comment: Right, thought that the number they return was milliseconds.

Comment: Yeah, that is why I don't like Unix time, too ambiguous. The OAuth spec is clear on which version though: http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc6749#section-4.2.2